# Can OKD (OpenShift Origin) be installed on RHEL 8?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

Can OpenShift Origin (OKD) be installed on RHEL 8? The documentation states minimal RHEL 7.4 or later: https://docs.okd.io/latest/install/prerequisites.html

However, RHEL 8 seems to be a major rework going on par with the commercial OpenShift 4. So I would assume the best version of RHEL to install OKD on is RHEL 7.6. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenShift v3.11 would install on RHEL v7.7 and also on v8.0. I have installed on both of these release levels of RHEL. On RHEL v8.0 - the container technology has moved to podman, buildah, UBI and related - still you can install docker ce and get OpenShift up and running. Thanks.

Comment: Switch from iptables to nftables is IMO the most significant difference going from el7 to el8. In addition, change from docker to cri-o on the OKD part would be another significant difference, assuming that's what really happens. Podman and buildah are user-facing tools, OKD does not touch that. Universal Base Images run on Docker just fine, so nothing dramatic there as well.

Comment: Hi Bharg, Since you installed Openshift v3.11, can you tell how to install Openshift v3.10 on Centos 8 since it is showing python errors as 'nothing provides python-six needed by openshift-ansible-3.10.68-1.git.0.f908cf5.el7.noarch'. Although I have already installed 'python3-six' in my environment.